# How to update the css class of my navbar component from another component in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

below is my progress bar component

```
    @Component ({
  selector: 'progress-bar',
  templateUrl: './progress-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-bar.component.css']
})



   export class ProgressBarComponent {


}
```

this is the html file

```
<div class="step-by-step">
  <ul class="unstyled clearfix">
    <li class="step step-ok"><span>step one</span></li>
    <li class="step step-ok"><span>step two</span></li>
    <li class="last-step step-ok"><span>step three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this is how my app component look like

import {Component} from "@angular/core";

```
@Component ({
  selector: '',


    templateUrl: `<navbar-component></navbar-component>

<progress-bar></progress-bar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
    })

    export class AppConfigurationComponent {

    }
```

for each of the pages to be navigated to i have created component for those pages(three in total) i want to be able to set the css class of the progress bar and i navigate through the pages

below is the image of the progress bar
[image]

Comment: what does your progressbar component will do? and refine your question with more relevant information.

Comment: the progress bar show the progress of the 3 pages been navigated....so the progress bar has 3 nodes...after navigating from the fist page, the first node in the progress bar is updated by changing the color....notice that the progress bar is in its own component while the other pages are in their own component. so there has to be a way to communicate between the components

Comment: The more simple way in this case is to create service for your progress bar. The component will subscribe to change and pass values to view accordingly. take a look here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to accomplish this, try this code in the **ProgressBarComponent**

```js
export class ProgressBarComponent implements OnInit {

  step = {
    one: true,
    two: false,
    three: false
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {

      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

          this.setStep(event.path);
      });
  }
  
  setStep(path){
  
    //replace the string with your actual component path
    this.step.two = (path === '/secondPage' || path === '/thirdPage') ? true : false;
    this.step.three = (path === '/thirdPage') ? true : false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="step-by-step">
  <ul class="unstyled clearfix">
    <li class="step" [class.step-ok]="step.one"><span>step one</span></li>
    <li class="step" [class.step-ok]="step.two"><span>step two</span></li>
    <li class="last-step" [class.step-ok]="step.three"><span>step three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This should work well. there are better solutions for sure, I recommend you to use an app state like [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store), then you can update this state from anywhere (better to update router changes from the root component) using the same method `this.router.events.subscribe`, and your *Progressbar* will update according to that state

Comment: Thanks.....but supposing i complete one step and i logout of the application, i want to be able to continue from the next step when i log back in...can this help me achieve it?

Comment: This works on the router, if you continue from the same route you get the same step. So it depends how your authentication works

Answer (score 0):

Try this in respective component

```
constructor(private router: Router){ 
    if(this.router.url == "/componentName") {
        $("progress-bar").addClass("home"); // add jquery or do it in angular way..
    }
}
```